# Calculate b such that $ P(-b<X<b) =0.9 $

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given the t-distribution X~t(14). How can I calculate b such that the following holds: $ P(-b<X<b) =0.9 $.

I would start with $ P(-b<X<b) =P(X<b)-P(X<-b)$ but then I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution. You'll find the cdf of the T-distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ P(-b<X<b) = P(X<b)-P(X<-b)$$

$$= 1 - P(X>b) -P(X<-b)$$

$$= 1 - P(X<-b) -P(X<-b) \ \text{Why?}$$

$$= 1 - 2P(X<-b)$$

Thus,

$$1 - 2P(X<-b) = 0.9$$

$$\to 0.1/2 = P(X<-b)$$

$$\to 0.05 = P(X<-b) = F_X(-b)$$

Let $c := - b$.

Then $0.05 = F_X(c)$

Use a computer or your t table to find such a c. Then find b.

---

Note: The above uses the fact that $P(X=b)=0 \ \forall b \in \mathbb R$

Comment: The one step is valid because of the symmetry of the distribution.

Comment: For b I would get 1.761

Comment: Can you confirm this?

Comment: craaaft, symmetry yeah. b i guess would be right if you looked up table or used a computer (eg wolframalpha, r, excel) :P

Comment: Yeah I looke dit up for n=14 and p=0.95